# Windows: How to delete files with a too long name?

Tags: windows, directory

I have a problem with delete, I would like to delete some folder which contains a number of files, and I am getting an error like:

> Cannot delete Folder: The file name
>   you specified is not valid or too
>   long. Specify a different file name.

How on earth can I delete this? How to force to delete it?

Comment: this is not Server Fault related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See http://www.ratsauce.co.uk/notablog/LongFilenames.asp

JR

PS for a folder use:

rd /S \\?\C:\VeryLongFolderName

Answer (score 2):

Try using a wildcard "*" after the first few characters of the name. Make sure you have enough differentiation so as not to delete what you don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a dir /x to get the [short file name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename), and then delete that.
e.g. C:\AReallyLongFolderName can also be accessed or deleted using C:\AREALL~1

Answer (score 1):

If it's on a network you can map a drive to the parent folder and delete it that way.  You may also be able to subst a non-networked drive.

Comment: And excellent suggestion that worked well for me given the file was nestled in a sophisticated and deep file sturcture.

Answer (score 0):

try to rename file or folder with smaller name or map folder as root then delete

Comment: The question says windows there is no root on windows.

Comment: but if you share folder at one computer at another you can map, like root this folder. it is decrease full path length.

Comment: "root" in this case is the top directory of a drive.  If you use SUBST you can create a drive letter that points to any directory you choose.